# Spring Data JPA Custom Query limit functionality not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have created a custom Query

```
@Repository
public interface SecurityQuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<SecurityQuestion, Integer>{

    @Query("select q from SecurityQuestion q order by q.questionId asc limit 0, 3 ")
    public List<SecurityQuestion> findQuestion();

}
```

When I call the service and invoked public `List<SecurityQuestion> findQuestion()` method `limit 0,3` is not working

Here is the hibernate log,

```
Hibernate: select securityqu0_.question_id as question1_4_, securityqu0_.question_desc as question2_4_ from user_security_question securityqu0_ order by securityqu0_.question_id asc
```

How to made this limit functionality working in this?

Comment: JPQL does not support "LIMIT", as any basic JPA documentation would tell you

Comment: As `limit` key word is not supported by few database vendors, mainly Oracle, I guess this is the reason it is not included in `JPQL`. Use `Pageable`, it can be easily converted to `ArrayList`...:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to pass a method parameter with type `Pageable`:

```
@Query("select q from SecurityQuestion q order by q.questionId asc")
public List<SecurityQuestion> findQuestion(Pageable page);
```

and when you call this function, init `page` like this:

```
securityQuestionRepository.findQuestion(new PageRequest(0, 3));
```

Or just use native query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
       value = "select * from user_security_question order by question_id asc limit 0, 3")
public List<SecurityQuestion> findQuestion();
```

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery = true,
       value = "select * from user_security_question order by question_id asc limit 0, 3")
public List<SecurityQuestion> findQuestion();                                                                     this is working fine

Comment: This is by far the best answer I have seen on this topic. Native query is always the least preferred option as it defeats the purpose of JPA. Consider that the “limit” functionality differs signlificantly between databases (postgres vs oracle for example)

Comment: Assuming you are using Java 8, you can add a `default List<SecurityQuestion> findQuestion() { return findQuestion(new PageRequest(0, 3)); }` so that the caller does not need to specify the `Pageable` argument.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simpler variant:

```
public interface SecurityQuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<SecurityQuestion, Integer>{

    List<SecurityQuestion> findTop3ByOrderByIdAsc();
}
```

More info is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).

Comment: This should be the top answer. No need to set up pageable results. Simple

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter `nativeQuery = true, value = "your query"` inside `@Query` annotation.