# <expression> expected, got ':'

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Oracle SQL query:

```
SELECT user FROM global_users user WHERE user.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND user.description IS NOT NULL AND user.updatedGoodsDate BETWEEN '2024-03-10 20:09:53' AND '2024-03-10 20:09:53'
AND ROWNUM <= 13
```

I tried to edit the query into Postgres with Spring Data JPA:

```
@Query("SELECT user FROM global_users user WHERE user.status = :status
AND user.description IS NOT NULL AND user.updatedGoodsDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
AND LIMIT :count")
List<Users> findTopUsers(@Param("status") TransactionStatus status,
  @Param("startDate") OffsetDateTime start, @Param("endDate") OffsetDateTime end, @Param("count") long count);
```

But for `LIMIT :count` I get `<expression> expected, got ':'`. Do you know how I can fix this?

Test code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/oracle_rownum_pg_migration_poc

Comment: i wouldnt put my hand in the fire but i think LIMIT is not part of WHERE, but of SELECT

Comment: Remove `AND` from `AND LIMIT :count`. `LIMIT` is a separate clause in PostgreSQL unlike Oracle where it is emulated in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I get error: `unexpected token: LIMIT`

Comment: @PeterPenzov `unexpected token: LIMIT` looks like an HQL error, not a PostgreSQL error. If you want to use PostgreSQL syntax, add a [`nativeQuery=true`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native). Note that while `SELECT user FROM global_users user` wil continue to function, you'll probably want `SELECT *`. If you want to stick to your current syntax, remove the `LIMIT` completely and `query.setMaxResults(count);`, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40576183/5298879).

Comment: It turns out that I can't use native query. Other possible option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe JPA does not support adding parameters for `LIMIT`.

You should be able to use Pageable to limit your result set, as shown in this answer: [JPA limit functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153464/spring-data-jpa-custom-query-limit-functionality-not-working)

In your case, this would look like:

```
@Query("SELECT user FROM global_users user WHERE user.status = :status
AND user.description IS NOT NULL AND user.updatedGoodsDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)

List<Users> findTopUsers(@Param("status") TransactionStatus status,
  @Param("startDate") OffsetDateTime start, @Param("endDate") OffsetDateTime end, **Pageable pageable)**;
```

Comment: Other possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SpringDataJPA 3.2 is possible to use Limit type.

As described here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results#3-using-limit :

> Spring Data JPA version 3.2 provides a new type named `Limit` to limit
> the number of results returned from a query. It has two static methods
> – of() and unlimited().
>
> The of() method accepts an integer as an argument.  It limits query
> results to the given maximum size. This allows fetching only the
> specified number of results.
>
> Next, the unlimited() method returns all the matching results from a
> query. it doesn’t restrict the number of results.
>
> Let’s use the of() method from Limit to limit the query result to 1:
>
> `List<Passenger> passenger = repository.findByOrderBySeatNumberAsc(Limit.of(1));`
>
> Here, we invoke the static method of() on Limit to return 1 result
> based on our specification.

Official documentation of Spring here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-methods-details.html#repositories.special-parameters

Comment: I use older version if Spring-JPA. Other possible options?

Comment: I added a test project. Please see updated post.

Comment: If you want to use LIMIT with spring-data-jpa (spring boot 2.6.x) without nativeQuery. You must use Pageable into query method. Note, you can specify only limit size creating pageable in this way `Pageable.ofSize(10)` where 10 is limit number (batchSize variable in your example repository).

Answer (score 0):

try this, put the native query flag in the @Query(value="select ...", nativeQuery=true) annotation.

For older versions of JPA, the correct dialect must be set for your bank. Check is with the dialect for postgres.

After the 2 steps above, use the LIMIT clause as in the example below

SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT :param;